# How do I add a custom pushpin (using an image source) to Bing Maps - Windows Store 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

Maybe I'm not searching the right keywords but I can't find an example of how to do this.
I have a PNG image of a pushpin that I want to place at a coordinate on the Bing Map control

Comment: You talking about something like [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Creating-Scaled-PushPins-73f6e253)?

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes thank you! However I ran into a problem, I'm stuck on adding the ResourceDictionary to App.xaml.  My app is targeting 8.1, but the sample is 8.0.

Comment: What's the problem? Just throw your templates you need into your proj dictionary, I wouldnt be trying to copy over anything else.

Comment: @ChrisW.sorry I forgot to mention, in my Application Resources, I already have a ControlTemplate followed by two Styles. And the error I get what I try adding the ResourceDictionary is "Error 5 Each dictionary entry must have an associated key."

Comment: Right, so does each template have a unique x:Key attached to it?

Comment: @ChrisW.Yes in my project, each has it's own key, so I solved the issue by giving it a key name.  That resolved the error.

Comment: ya sorry, should have been more specific with the x:Key="UniqueName" part, either way as long as you've got what you need :)